# I think I'm flooded on apache

Tags: linux

Too many processes being spawned on apache server start. Is there a way to reduce it.

http://s21.postimg.org/s593hjoaf/flood.jpg

Comment: Are you actually having a problem? That looks (relatively) normal.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the number in StartServers and MaxServers directive in your apache configuration file and restart apache.